# How to check if three coordinates form a line

Tags: coordinate-systems

Assume I have three coordinates from a world map in Longitude + Latitude. Is there a way to determine these three coordinates form a straight line?

What if I was using a system with bounds that defines the 2 corners (northeast - southwest) in Long/Lat?

The long & lat are expressed in decimal degrees.

Comment: What do you mean by "straight line"? Do you mean great circle?

Comment: What do you mean by "Longitude + Latitude" versus "Degrees"? lat&long are usually measured *in* degrees (though they can be expressed either as degrees,minutes,seconds or decimal degrees).

Comment: I'm not a mathematician at all, so I'm really referring to the most basic meaning: if you draw the 3 points on a map you can connect the three of them and they form a straight line. 

@Ben: I'll remove the degrees part since every API I've checked so far only uses Long/Lat.

Comment: You mean that they are collinear.

Comment: @MhenniBenghorbal: That's indeed the term I was looking for!

Comment: You are talking about a world map in two dimensions which is a stereographic projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a point has longitude $\alpha$ (from $-180^\circ$ to $+180^°$) and latitude $\beta$ (from $-90^°$ to $+90^°$), the corresponding 3D point is 
$$ (x,y,z)=(\cos\alpha\cos\beta,\sin\alpha\cos\beta,\sin\beta).$$
If you have three such points, the determinant
$$ \left|\begin{matrix}x_1&x_2&x_3\\y_1&y_2&y_3\\z_1&z_2&z_3\end{matrix}\right|$$
is zero if and only if the plane through the three points passes through the Earth center.
In the presence of rounding errors aou will never have *exactly* zero, so the question is when to accept an almost zero value as good ...

A simplified alternative: If all your points are relatively close to one another (e.g. less than 100km apart and not too close to the poles), it is a not-too-bad approximation to work with the angles themselves (after all viewing the Earth as a sphere is also just an approximation) as $x$ and $y$ coordinates and check collinearity, that is
$$ \left|\begin{matrix}\alpha_1&\alpha_2&\alpha_3\\\beta_1&\beta_2&\beta_3\\1&1&1\end{matrix}\right|\approx 0.$$

Comment: Preferably I would like to work with a margin error of only a few meters (say 10-15 meters at max): is this possible, or can this sort of accuracy not be reached? The points can be up to 4000 km apart, so the second method won't be an option.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume that by "line" you mean "great circle" -- that is, if you want to go from A to C via the shortest possible route, then keep going straight until you circle the globe and get back to A, you'll pass B on the way.

The best coordinates for the question to be in are cartesian -- the 3D vector from the center of the earth to the point on the map. (Lat/long are two thirds of a set of "spherical coordinates", and can be converted to cartesian coordinates given the radius of the earth as $r$, though for this question $r$ doesn't matter).

Once you have those points, which each one being a 3D vector), find the plane containing them, and check that it includes the center of the earth.

Or, as a shortcut, just mark the points on a [Gnomonic projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gnomonic_projection) map, and use a ruler to see if they form a straight line there. Unfortunately, a given gnomonic projection map can't include the whole world.

Comment: I will perform this check on coordinates for thousands of them, so a manual check isn't really suited. Would you mind expanding a little on the 3rd paragraph? Do you perhaps have a link to an example of this usage?

Comment: It might be easier to just check the determinant of the three vectors in cartesian coordinates. This has the advantage of being very easy to set up numerically (which I assume you intend to do), as you can specify a threshold under which you can consider the points as on a great circle.

Comment: I concur -- that's the easiest way for checking the coplanarity. But now that I think about it, one weakness of that is that if the determinant is NOT zero, the threshold doesn't tell you much -- it'll be larger for longer paths, even with the same amount of "sideways" wandering. I think a more robust solution would be to find the solid angle defined by the three points (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_angle#Tetrahedron), then divide that by the largest angle formed between any two of the three points.

Answer (score 0):

The following MATLAB code might do the trick

```
function result = collinear(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, lat3, lon3)
% result = collinear(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2, lat3, lon3)
%
% returns a measure of the collinearity of the points (lat1,lon1),
% (lat2,lon2), (lat3,lon3) defined as follows:
%
% Find the middle point (opposite the longest edge); for the sake
% of illustration assume this is point 2.  Compute bearings at
% point 2 for the line from 1 to 2 and from 2 to 3.  If the points
% are collinear, these bearings are equal.  So use the difference
% in bearings (in degrees) as the measure of collinearity.
%
% Requires the package
%  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39108
%
% This version is not vectorized.  It would be relatively easy to
% make it vectorized.
  lata = [lat1; lat2; lat3];  lona = [lon1; lon2; lon3];
  latb = [lat2; lat3; lat1];  lonb = [lon2; lon3; lon1];
  [s12, azi1, azi2] = geoddistance(lata, lona, latb, lonb);
  imax = find(s12 == max(s12));
  imax = imax(1);
  ia = mod(imax,3)+1; ib = mod(imax+1,3)+1;
  azia = azi2(ia); azib = azi1(ib);
  result = azib - azia;
  if result >= 180
    result = result - 360;
  elseif result < -180
    result = result + 360;
end
```

Alternatively you can divide the area of the triangle (given by geodarea) by the longest sides to get a measure of how far the opposite point is from the longest side.